# 256 MB emulator shortcut

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1.1

Does anyone have the full command line that needs to go in the shortcut target to launch the 256MB emulator in the Windows Phone 7.1.1 CTP?  The docs say to append " - 256 MB;" but that doesn't seem to work in my environment (Windows 7 / Visual Studio 2010 / WP 7.1 SDK and tools / 7.1.1 CTP SDK).

Comment: You might want to add "your environment" to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command, replacing the path with the path on your machine:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\XDE Launcher\XdeLauncher.exe" "Windows Phone 7" "Windows Phone Emulator - 256 MB"